# Error with OWLEntityRenamer in renaming IRIs

Tags: java, owl, ontology, semantic-web, owl-api

I am using OWLEntityRenamer to replace the IRIs in my ontology. For this purpose, I am using the human.owl ontology from [OAEI](https://oaei.ontologymatching.org/2022/anatomy/index.html). While OWLEntityRenamer effectively modifies IRIs containing the fragment/remainder "NCI_*" (the IRI containing this fragmanet may look like this: `http://human.owl#NCI_C52809`), it is unable to replace IRIs that resemble this pattern:

`http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#Definition`.

Unable to change the above IRI it throws a **NullExceptionError** that looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLObjectDuplicator.visit(OWLObjectDuplicator.java:809)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLAnonymousIndividualImpl.accept(OWLAnonymousIndividualImpl.java:89)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLObjectDuplicator.visit(OWLObjectDuplicator.java:158)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLClassAssertionAxiomImpl.accept(OWLClassAssertionAxiomImpl.java:123)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLObjectDuplicator.duplicateObject(OWLObjectDuplicator.java:104)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLEntityRenamer.fillListWithTransformChanges(OWLEntityRenamer.java:185)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLEntityRenamer.changeIRI(OWLEntityRenamer.java:86)
....
```

I still don't understand why this error is happening.  I suspect it may be related to the `www.geneontology.org` namespace, but I'm uncertain.

Any insights or guidance on resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.

*P.S.*

*I simple call the OWLEntityRenamer like this:*

```
changedClassesOntology1 = renamer.changeIRI(class1, capitalClass);
changedClassesOntology2 = renamer.changeIRI(class2, capitalClass);
```

*where capitalClass are just unique IRIs I create using the code `IRI.create(uniqueIRI)`.*

Comment: Hello an welcome on StackOverflow! Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to help us to solve the problem.

Comment: @logi-kal I've made some modifications on my post. In case you have any another question please feel free to ask in order to help. Thank you :)